# Get a list of files in a sub folder in the Documents Library of Sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, api

I am trying to find the best way to get files inside a specific sub folder in the sharepoint website, but the only links I find relate to the root folders.

I have a Sharepoint site which is really just a fileAttachments repository.

The Documents page of the website has folder for each customer.
Then In each Customer folder there is another folder named for a CaseNumber.
And in that Case Number folder, I drop all file attachments.

I am able to create the Customer folders and then a sub folder for the Case Number folder.  And then I can upload files just fine through code.

I just can't seem to use the Context to retrieve the list of files in one of those sub folders (NOT THE ROOT FOLDER).

Can someone please advise how I can get the list of files with the following inputs?

sharePointBaseURL = "https://mySample.sharepoint.com"
siteName          = "CustomerCaseAttachments"
libraryName       = "Documents"

FOR EXAMPLE,  Assume there is a ROOT folder for customer
CustomerName = "Customer_A"
Assume that in the Customer_A folder, there is a subfolder for the
CaseNumber = "123456"
Finally, assume there a two files in that folder "logFile1.txt" and "Capture.jpg"

So I need to write a function that will take CustomerName and CaseNumber to identify the two folder and subfolder on the site.  Then Return the list of files in that subfolder

[image]

```
##############
##  UPDATE  ##
##############
```

I figured out how to do it, but still ask the question if there is not a better way?

Here is the function I came up with.

```
Public Function GetFileListFromSharepoint_Datatable(CustomerName As String, CaseNumber As String) As DataTable
    Dim dtAttachments As DataTable = FileAttachmentDatatableWithHeaders()
    Dim spCon As New SharepointConnector()
    Try
        Dim siteUrl As String = $"{spCon.config.SharePointBaseURL}/sites/{spCon.config.SiteName}"
        Dim serverRelativeUrl As String = $"/sites/{spCon.config.SiteName}/{spCon.config.libraryName}"
        Dim FileIsOnSharepoint As Boolean = False
        Using ctx As ClientContext = spCon.CreateSharepointClientContext()
            Dim ctxWeb As Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web = ctx.Web
            Dim rootFolderList As Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List = ctxWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents")
            ctx.Load(rootFolderList)
            ctx.Load(rootFolderList.RootFolder.Folders)
            ctx.Load(rootFolderList.RootFolder.Files)
            ctx.ExecuteQuery()
            Dim listOfCustomerFolders As FolderCollection = rootFolderList.RootFolder.Folders
            For Each customerFolder In listOfCustomerFolders
                If customerFolder.Name = CustomerName Then
                    ctx.Load(customerFolder)
                    ctx.Load(customerFolder.Folders)
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                    Dim listOfCaseFolders As FolderCollection = customerFolder.Folders()
                    For Each caseFolder In listOfCaseFolders
                        If caseFolder.Name = CaseNumber Then
                            ctx.Load(caseFolder)
                            ctx.Load(caseFolder.Files)
                            ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                            Dim listOfFiles As FileCollection = caseFolder.Files
                            For Each f In listOfFiles
                                Dim dr As DataRow = dtAttachments.Rows.Add
                                dr("Id") = f.ServerRelativeUrl
                                dr("FileName") = f.Name
                                dr("Size") = BytesToString(f.Length)
                                dr("ChangedDate") = f.TimeLastModified
                            Next
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        logger.Error(ex)
    End Try
    Return dtAttachments
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`CamlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee536450(v=office.15)) property to indicate the target folder.

Screen capture from [Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code | Retrieve items from a SharePoint list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code#retrieve-items-from-a-sharepoint-list).

[image]

In your case you would use something like:

```
List documentsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
query.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/Documents/Customer_A/123456";
ListItemCollection items = documentsList.GetItems(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get-PnPListItem -List "Shared Documents" -FolderServerRelativeUrl "/sites/CustomerCaseAttachments/Shared Documents/Customer_A/123456"

Retrieves all list items from the 123456 folder